# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'pivot'

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, pivot, attributeerror

I have PySpark dataframe:

| user_id | item_id | last_watch_dt | total_dur | watched_pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-05-11 | 4250 | 72 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-05-11 | 80 | 99 |
| 2 | 3 | 2021-05-11 | 1000 | 80 |
| 2 | 4 | 2021-05-11 | 5000 | 40 |

I used this code:

```py
df_new = df.pivot(index='user_id', columns='item_id', values='watched_pct')
```

To get this:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 72 | 99 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 80 | 40 |

But I got an error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'pivot'

What did I do wrong?

Comment: did you mean pivot_table?

Comment: I used both, and the error remains

Comment: Ah just re-read your probem, this is not a pandas DataFrame? Well clearly this object does not have a pivot method.

Comment: Quick google search shows pivot being called on a groupby object, not on the dataframe itself

Comment: I can use df_new = df.groupBy("user_id").pivot("item_id"), but how do I fill it with watched_pct values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do `.pivot` on objects having `pivot` *attribute* (method or property).  You tried to do `df.pivot`, so it would only work if `df` had such attribute. You can inspect all the attributes of df (it's an object of `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` class) [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame). You see many attributes there, but none of them is called `pivot`. That's why you get an *attribute error*.

[`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot) is a method of `pyspark.sql.GroupedData` object. It means, in order to use it, you must somehow create `pyspark.sql.GroupedData` object from your `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` object. In your case, it's by using `.groupBy()`:

```py
df.groupBy("user_id").pivot("item_id")
```

This creates yet another `pyspark.sql.GroupedData` object. In order to make a dataframe out of it you would want to use one of the methods of `GroupedData` class. [**`agg`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.agg.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.agg) is the method that you need. Inside it, you will have to provide Spark's aggregation function which you will use for all the grouped elements (e.g. `sum`, `first`, etc.).

```py
df.groupBy("user_id").pivot("item_id").agg(F.sum("watched_pct"))
```

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1, '2021-05-11', 4250, 72),
     (1, 2, '2021-05-11', 80, 99),
     (2, 3, '2021-05-11', 1000, 80),
     (2, 4, '2021-05-11', 5000, 40)],
    ['user_id', 'item_id', 'last_watch_dt', 'total_dur', 'watched_pct'])

df = df.groupBy("user_id").pivot("item_id").agg(F.sum("watched_pct"))
df.show()
# +-------+----+----+----+----+
# |user_id|   1|   2|   3|   4|
# +-------+----+----+----+----+
# |      1|  72|  99|null|null|
# |      2|null|null|  80|  40|
# +-------+----+----+----+----+
```

If you want to replace nulls with `0`, use [`fillna`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna) of `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` class.

```py
df = df.fillna(0)
df.show()
# +-------+---+---+---+---+
# |user_id|  1|  2|  3|  4|
# +-------+---+---+---+---+
# |      1| 72| 99|  0|  0|
# |      2|  0|  0| 80| 40|
# +-------+---+---+---+---+
```